# I am having trouble to utilize a WindowsForms method in a different thread (C++)

Tags: c++, .net, visual-studio, winforms, console

Sorry for my english, if something is not clear, please ask me. I am having trouble to make that application for WindowsForms ("ThreadTeste" is a representation of "MyForm1"):

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

using namespace  std;
using namespace std::chrono;

class ThreadTeste
{
    public:
    void loop()
    {
        for(int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++)
        {
            cout << i << endl;
            this_thread::sleep_for(seconds(1));
        }
    }
    thread getThread()
    {
        return thread(&ThreadTeste::loop, this);
    }
    
    ThreadTeste()
    {
        thread myThread = getThread();
        myThread.detach();
    }
 
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  
    ThreadTeste* t = new ThreadTeste();
    while(true)
    {
        cout << "Working" << endl;
        this_thread::sleep_for(seconds(1));
    }
} 
//That works!!
```

D:

Comment: So what's exactly your question? Whst kind of trouble do you have?

Comment: WinForms is a C# technology. It cannot be used in C++. It can be used in C++/CLI though. We don't see a single piece of code that confirms that you are working in C++/CLI so this question is a bit confusing.

Comment: Could you please tell me what you want to do and what is your problem? So that it will help solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to output from 0 to 4 and then output `working`, then you could not use `detach`. Because `detach` means that the main thread does not need to wait for the execution of the child thread to complete and the two are out of relationship,then it will run by itself.

You could use `join`.

```
ThreadTeste()
    {
        thread myThread = getThread();
        myThread.join();
    }
```